# Sparse Voxel Octrees

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, voxel

I'm looking for all materials, books that will allow me to build simplest voxel rendering engine oparating on sparse voxel octrees. I will probabbly be using python or more likely javascript so lots of things have to be written from scratch as webGL/openGL doesn't support voxels. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Space-filling-curves: z-curve, hilbert curve, moore curve, quadkey, spatial index.

Answer (score 2):

this is one I referred to before when I had an interest in voxels:

http://www.flipcode.com/voxtut/

You'll have to convert the source yourself, but at should at least introduce you to the basic concepts.

For a specific reference on SVO, there was a whitepaper released by NVidia, but it's a bit heavy on the math:  http://www.tml.tkk.fi/~samuli/publications/laine2010tr1_paper.pdf

Comment: I've seen the flipcode site. But I don't want to cheat using height maps :)

Comment: Yup, well the heightmap is just a mapping system, I thought if you're looking for the simplest method, it'd be best to start at the beginning.  If you abstract your Mapping method, you could start with a heightmap and then add an SVO method when your ready.

Answer (score 1):

Check this blogpost for an octree traversal algorithm: http://www.forceflow.be/2012/05/10/ray-octree-traversal-parametric-algorithm-implementation/